# Using identical() in R with multiple vectors

Tags: r

Suppose that I have five vectors:

```
A<-1:10
B<-1:10
C<-1:10
D<-1:10
E<-1:12
```

I could test two at a time using identical( ).

```
identical(A,C)
```

But I want to test ALL of them at once to see if ANY is different from the others. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would just pick one, say `A`, and do all pair-wise comparisons with it.

```
all(sapply(list(B, C, D, E), FUN = identical, A))
# [1]  FALSE
```

Remove the `all()` to see the not identical one(s)

```
sapply(list(B, C, D, E), FUN = identical, A)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`identical` ought to be transitive, so if `A` is identical to `C` and to `D`, then `C` should be identical to `D`.

(Thanks to @docendo discimus for simplified syntax.)

Comment: A slight improvement would be to use the all( ) function in front of sapply( ) so that it returns a single true/false.

Answer (score 17):

First thought is to do `unique` on a list of the vectors and check the length. If there are two or more vectors that are different, then the length of the resulting list will be greater than 1.

```
length(unique(list(A,B,C,D))) == 1
[1] TRUE

length(unique(list(A,B,C,D,E))) == 1
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I quite liked the elegance of this answer, but I'm going to mark @Gregor's as the best.

Comment: @Andy, it is the better answer given that it still uses `identical`.  I should have thought of the transitive comparisons :P

Answer (score 10):

Another option, just for fun:

```
Vectorize(identical, 'x')(list(A, B, C, D, E), C)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty obvious, but: if there are a lot of elements and a good chance of failure, you'll want to be able to short circuit the comparisons. Here's a loop for that, with an example:

```
A = sample(1e3)
Alist <- replicate(1e6,A,simplify=FALSE)
Alist[[2]][1e3] <- 0

system.time({brkres <- {
  ok=TRUE
  for (i in seq_along(Alist)) if( !identical(Alist[[1]],Alist[[i]]) ){
    ok=FALSE
    break
  }
  ok
}})
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0 

system.time({allres <- all(sapply(Alist[-1], FUN = identical, Alist[[1]]))})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.66    0.03    1.68
```

If you skip the `Alist[[2]][1e3] <- 0` line, so that they are all identical, they take the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and simple solution using `Rcpp`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

inline bool same(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
    return R_compute_identical(a, b, 0);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool identical_impl(List x) {
    std::size_t n = x.size();
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (!same(x[0], x[i])) return false;
    return true;
}

/*** R
identical2 <- function(...) {
    identical_impl(list(...))
}
*/
```

Some benchmarks with other solutions:

```r
A <- 1:10
B <- 1:10
C <- 1:10
D <- 1:10
E <- 1:12
identical2 <- function(...) {
    identical_impl(list(...))
}
identical3 <- function(...) {
    length(unique(list(...))) == 1L
}
identical4 <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    all(vapply(l[-1], l[[1]], FUN = identical,
               FUN.VALUE = logical(1L), USE.NAMES = FALSE))
}
identical5 <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    Vectorize(identical, 'x')(l[-1], l[[1L]])
}
identical6 <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    for (i in seq_along(l)) {
        if (!identical(l[[1]], l[[i]])) return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
}
identical7 <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    for (i in seq_along(l)) {
        for (j in seq_along(l)) {
            if (i >= j) next
            if (!identical(l[[1]], l[[i]])) return(FALSE)
        }
    }
    return(TRUE)
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    identical2(A, B, C, D, E),
    identical3(A, B, C, D, E),
    identical4(A, B, C, D, E),
    identical5(A, B, C, D, E),
    identical6(A, B, C, D, E),
    identical7(A, B, C, D, E))
```

Results:

```
Unit: microseconds
                     expr    min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval   cld
identical2(A, B, C, D, E)  3.401  4.3065  5.32136  5.1245   5.5420  21.529   100 a    
identical3(A, B, C, D, E)  6.480  7.8675  9.20970  8.3875   9.0175  26.739   100  b   
identical4(A, B, C, D, E) 12.233 13.5680 15.48014 14.7755  15.5455  48.333   100   c  
identical5(A, B, C, D, E) 90.177 93.1480 98.79570 95.2685 103.2765 178.657   100     e
identical6(A, B, C, D, E) 10.683 12.0650 13.43184 12.6820  13.4060  22.314   100   c  
identical7(A, B, C, D, E) 28.202 31.0800 34.97819 32.4630  39.4960  68.902   100    d
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but decided to implement a solution based on `Reduce` and one based on a double `for` loop.

Functions:

```
all_elements_the_same = function(list) {

  #func to compare with
  comparison_func = function(x, y) {
    if (!identical(x, y)) stop() #stop function if it finds a non-identical pair
    y #return second element
  }

  #run comparisons
  trial = try({
    Reduce(f = comparison_func, x = list, init = list[[1]])
  }, silent = T)

  #return
  if (class(trial) == "try-error") return(F)
  T
}

all_elements_the_same2 = function(list, ignore_names = F) {
  #double loop solution
  for (i in seq_along(list)) {
    for (j in seq_along(list)) {
      #skip if comparing to self or if comparison already done
      if (i >= j) next

      #check
      if (!identical(list[[i]], list[[j]])) return(F)
    }
  }
  T
}
```

Test objects:

```
l_testlist_ok = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
l_testlist_bad = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:4, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
l_testlist_bad2 = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:4, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
```

Test functionality:

```
> all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_ok)
[1] TRUE
> all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad)
[1] FALSE
> all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad2)
[1] FALSE
> all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_ok)
[1] TRUE
> all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad)
[1] FALSE
> all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad2)
[1] FALSE
```

Test time use:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_ok),
+ all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad),
+ all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad2),
+ all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_ok),
+ all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad),
+ all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad2), times = 1e4)
Unit: microseconds
                                    expr    min      lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
    all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_ok) 19.310  25.454  28.309016  26.917  28.380 1003.228 10000
   all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad) 93.624 100.938 108.890823 103.863 106.497 3130.807 10000
  all_elements_the_same(l_testlist_bad2) 93.331 100.938 107.963741 103.863 106.497 1181.404 10000
   all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_ok) 48.275  53.541  57.334095  55.881  57.930  926.866 10000
  all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad)  6.144   7.315   8.437603   7.900   8.778  998.839 10000
 all_elements_the_same2(l_testlist_bad2)  6.144   7.315   8.564780   8.192   8.778 1323.594 10000
```

So apparently, the `try` part slows it down considerably. It may still save time to use the `Reduce` variant if one has very large objects, but for smaller objects, double `for` loop seems the way to go.