# check column names and bind them

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

i have a data frame where      row      column names

```
a <- c("Round_and_Centre", "Number", "Round")
b <- c("Round_and_Centre", "Number", "Round")
c <- c("Round_and_Centre", "Number", "Round")
```

I want to check whether the names in each column are identical with same column names fn...if they are identical, i need to rbind the rows to get output

I cant find the function to check the column names and give output true if they are identical. if the output is true, then rbind them

Comment: You can use `identical` i.e. `identical(a,b)`

Comment: names(a)
[1] "Round_and_Centre" "number"           
[3] "Round"                
> names(b)
[1] "Round_and_Centre" "number"           
[3] "Round"                
> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE

Comment: im getting output as false even though the col names are same

Comment: I get `identical(a,b)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: is it possible to check whether more than 3 functions are same using identical function?

Comment: Try `all(combn(c("a", "b", "c"),2, FUN = function(x) identical(get(x[1]), get(x[2]))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is

```
all(unlist(Map(`==`, list(a), list(b,c))))
```

Or use `combn`

```
all(combn(c("a", "b", "c"),2, FUN = function(x) identical(get(x[1]), get(x[2]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (all(colnames(a)==colnames(b))&all(colnames(a)==colnames(c)&all(colnames(b)==colnames(c)){
  d <- rbind(a,b)
  e <- rbind(d,c)
{
```

Comment: is it possible to get a easierer solution to check whether 5 columns are identical and then bind them?

Comment: Here is exactly the solution to your challenge :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850400/using-identical-in-r-with-multiple-vectors