# find number of columns that contain a value in data.frame with mixed types

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like the number of columns that contain a specific value in a specific type in my data.frame.
Apparrently strings and numbers are treated the same. Is there a way to differentiate between strings and numbers?

```
foo <- data.frame(x = c("1", "2", "-99", "4", "5"), y = c(11, 12, -99, -99, 15))
#gives 2 but should be 1:     
sum(apply(foo, 2, function(x) {-99 %in% x})) 
#gives 2 but should be 1: 
sum(apply(foo, 2, function(x) {"-99" %in% x}))
```

Comment: From `?Comparison`: *If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
sum(sapply(foo, function(x) any(sapply(x, identical, -99))))
#> 1
sum(sapply(foo, function(x) any(sapply(x, identical, "-99"))))
#> 1
```

If you're looking for efficient methods to vectorize `identical`, you can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850400/using-identical-in-r-with-multiple-vectors)